# checking that information in <K> columns is the same

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table, that can have anywhere between 1 to 4 columns that indicate `NOplans`. On the beginning of the process it is unknown how many column will be present (`K` = number of columns), so I wrote this to check equality in every case:

```
setDT(plansCount)
if(K == 4){
  plansCount <- plansCount[NOplansnext== NOplans & NOplans == historicalNOplans2 &  historicalNOplans2 == historicalNOplans3 & historicalNOplans3 == historicalNOplans4]
} else if(K == 3) {
  plansCount <- plansCount[NOplansnext== NOplans & NOplans == historicalNOplans2 & historicalNOplans2 == historicalNOplans3]
} else if(K == 2){
  plansCount <- plansCount[ NOplansnext== NOplans & NOplans == historicalNOplans2]
} else {
 plansCount <- plansCount[NOplansnext == NOplans] 
}
```

This solution works, but is not particularly nice. Is there a better approach, one that is less repetitive?

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve]. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data:

```r
mt <- as.data.table(mtcars[,c(1,8:11)])
names(mt)[-1] <- c("NOplansnext", paste0("historicalNOplans", 2:4))
mt
#      mpg NOplansnext historicalNOplans2 historicalNOplans3 historicalNOplans4
#  1: 21.0           0                  1                  4                  4
#  2: 21.0           0                  1                  4                  4
#  3: 22.8           1                  1                  4                  1
#  4: 21.4           1                  0                  3                  1
#  5: 18.7           0                  0                  3                  2
# ---                                                                          
# 28: 30.4           1                  1                  5                  2
# 29: 15.8           0                  1                  5                  4
# 30: 19.7           0                  1                  5                  6
# 31: 15.0           0                  1                  5                  8
# 32: 21.4           1                  1                  4                  2
```

Dynamically find columns that contain a value:

```r
NOplans <- 2
mt[, rowSums(.SD == NOplans) > 0, .SDcols=patterns("NOplans")]
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [16] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [31] FALSE  TRUE
mt[ mt[, rowSums(.SD == NOplans) > 0, .SDcols = patterns("NOplans")], ]
#      mpg NOplansnext historicalNOplans2 historicalNOplans3 historicalNOplans4
#  1: 18.7           0                  0                  3                  2
#  2: 24.4           1                  0                  4                  2
#  3: 22.8           1                  0                  4                  2
#  4: 30.4           1                  1                  4                  2
#  5: 15.5           0                  0                  3                  2
#  6: 15.2           0                  0                  3                  2
#  7: 19.2           0                  0                  3                  2
#  8: 26.0           0                  1                  5                  2
#  9: 30.4           1                  1                  5                  2
# 10: 21.4           1                  1                  4                  2
```

The tricks:

- `data.table::patterns` lets us choose columns dynamically
- `.SDcols` defines the columns visible in `.SD`, used in the `j=` component of the `[`-expression
- `.SD == NOplans` creates a `matrix` of true/false, and `rowSums(...) > 0` finds rows that have at least one true
- since all of that returns a vector of true/false, we wrap `mt[ ..., ]` to use those logicals to define the rows to return

Comment: It's unclear to me from the OP whether `NOplans` is a column or a constant. If it's a column, the answer still works but would need some change like `patterns("NOplans.+")` to exclude the column itself.

Comment: I agree completely. There is enough ambiguity that I chose a path and went with it, pending an error or update from the OP. Thanks, @Frank.